# unmet dependency on eigen for vision-opencv, now can't install or upgrade any fuerte packages

Tags: ros, eigen, ros-fuerte, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I  tried to install vision-opencv today, and get failed dependencies due to a newer version of eigen3 (actually orocos depends on eigen, and geometry depends on orocos, and then vision-opencv depends on geometry). how can i resolve this? uninstalling eigen does not help as I get the same error.  I tried uninstalling fuerte, but now cannot reinstall fuerte due to the same error.

[rdean@RCTA-HSS81P1 impl]$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-vision-opencv

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 100%

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-vision-opencv: Depends: ros-fuerte-geometry (= 1.8.2-s1344793447~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics (= 0.2.3-s1344793277~lucid) but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
[rdean@RCTA-HSS81P1 impl]$ sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 100%

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics: Depends: libeigen3-dev (= 3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid) but 3.0.2-3+lucid1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
[rdean@RCTA-HSS81P1 impl]$ sudo apt-get install -f ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics

Reading package lists... 0%

Reading package lists... 100%

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 0%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree... 50%

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... 0%

Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
ros-fuerte-orocos-kinematics-dynamics: Depends: libeigen3-dev (= 3.0.1-1+ros4~lucid) but 3.0.2-3+lucid1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
[rdean@RCTA-HSS81P1 impl]$

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42596/unmet-dependency-on-eigen-for-vision-opencv,-now-can%27t-install-or-upgrade-any-fuerte-packages/) by [Bob Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/2328/bob-dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-08-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks like the repo got into an inconsistent state.  It should be cleared up by now?

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0